# firebase realtime funtions using multiple databases

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

We have two different firebase projects each with its own firebase functions and realtime database used.

we have come to a situation where we want to leverage one of the dataset (a node in the realtime db) from project 1 into the project 2.

As this node is read-only true so i can a access it in the format

https://myproject.firebaseio.com/prj1db/nodeX.json

but that will give entire data for this node. What i need is to query specific data like i do using below format for the db attached to the same project in the firebase function:

```
 const rsp = await db.ref("/users/").orderByChild("color").equalTo("pink).once("value")
```

is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So above answer did not work even being super close to what i need. The above response ends up giving error indicating there is a security issue.

What worked for me was that i used the service key approach with below code

```
 const scanbuddyDBApp = admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert("./src/scanbuddy_service_key.json"),
   databaseURL: "https://mydb.firebaseio.com",
 }, 'scanbuddy');
```